# How can I correctly use LazySubsets from Wolfram's Lazy package?

Tags: combinatorics, lazy-computations

I know that `Subsets[list]` gives the power set of list and `Subsets[list,{k}]` gives all subsets containing exactly $k$ elements.

They all give all the subsets at once. I want to output them iteratively.

I saw that Wolfram has a package called [Lazy](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/Wolfram/Lazy/). I installed it according to the instructions. However, when I tried to run the code below, it didn't work.

[image]

```
Needs["Wolfram`Lazy`"]
LazySubsets[{1, 2, 3}]
```

It will output as it is.

Or when I enter the following code, it even throws an error.

```
LazySubsets[{1, 2}]
```

> Lazy::undef: function `LazyMap` is undefined for the argument `LazySubsets[2]`.

> Lazy::undef: function `LazyJoin` is undefined for the argument `LazyMap[LazyPrepend[#1, 1]&, LazySubsets[2]]`.

I am not quite sure how to use this function either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The package doesn't seem to be well-documented, so I have to guess. If I guess it right, those `Lazy*` functions are supposed to work only on `LazyList[…]`. Following this conjecture, I find the following 3 solutions:

```
LazySubsets[LazyRange[2]]
% // Normal
```

[image]

```
LazySubsets[Lazy@Range[2]]
% // Normal
```

[image]

```
LazySubsets[ToLazyList@{1, 2}]
% // Normal
```

[image]

`Normal`s in code sample above have generated the subsets all at once. To obtain the subset *one by one*, `Part` (`[[]]`) / `LazyPart` seems to be the tool. The following code sample finds the first subset of `Range[10]` whose sum equals `12`:

```
lazylist = LazySubsets@LazyRange@10;
Catch@Do[With[{l = Normal@lazylist[[i]]}, 
              If[12 == Total@l, Throw@l]], 
      {i, ∞}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {16.5285, {1, 2, 3, 6}} *)
```

Hmm… a bit slow, but it indeed works.

Comment: Nice!  I would like to know how to iterate the output. It seems that `Normal` also provides output all at once. For example, if I find a subset of `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` where the product or sum of all elements is `12`, then break the iterate-loop.

Comment: @licheng I fail to figure out a way to achieve this, you may consider asking a new question. (But since the function is mentioned only on the page _Guide (internal)_, **personally** I suspect its functionality may not be complete. )

Comment: @licheng Finally, I find a possible solution to obtain the output _one by one_. Check my update.

Comment: It is indeed feasible, but the speed is discouraging. Let me check some other similar posts. It seems that Mathematica tends to prefer batch output instead of individual output to save memory.

Comment: `NextSubset` in `Combinatorica` is excellent, but unfortunately, Mathematica hasn't packaged it as an official built-in function. Maple's Iterator package provides a good solution for this. In Python, the `itertools` or `more-itertools` libraries also offer rich generator functionality.

Answer (score 11):

I made [my own lazy list paclet](https://github.com/ssmit1986/lazyLists/tree/main) a few years ago. It implements a fairly efficient lazy version of `Tuples` based on some old functionality from the deprecated `Combinatorica` package. It seems like that package also has code that's useful for generating subsets iteratively. You can use `NextSubset` to step through the subsets at your own pace:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
NestList[NextSubset[{a, b, c}, #] &, {}, 8]
```

Let me know if you need any help with the paclet I wrote; the usage is a bit arcane at times, but it can be quite efficient if used correctly.

## Edit

As remarked in the comments, Combinatorica has some conflicts with system symbols. As a precaution you can load and use it like this:

```
Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["Combinatorica`" -> "CM`"]]
NestList[CM`NextSubset[{a, b, c}, #] &, {}, 8]
```

The `Block` will prevent contamination of your context path. You'll still get messages, but I don't think it'll cause any harm. And if you're really paranoid, you can always use

```
CM`NextSubset // GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions
```

to figure out how it's defined and reverse-engineer it from there.

## Edit 2

I honestly forgot the most obvious way to do this: you can use the 3rd argument of `Subsets` to pick whichever element you want. E.g., get the 20th subset of length 50 from the subsets of `Range[100]`:

```
Subsets[Range[100], {50}, {20}]
```

You can easily iterate over that.

Comment: Good! I also noticed your package. Once Combinatorica is loaded, it can conflict with many built-in functions like the Graph function. I'm not sure how to make them coexist peacefully.

Comment: I'm not quite sure where the source code for the Wolfram package  `Lazy` is located, so I don't know how to use it either.

Comment: @licheng See the update to my question

Comment: @licheng See my 2nd edit for an even better solution.

Comment: Nice answer! However, since I specifically asked about the `Lasy` library, considering the topic, I did not select your answer as the best. But, in terms of actual effectiveness, your answer is the best.